# probability: Relays used in the construction of electric circuits function properly with probability .9

Tags: probability

[image: relay]

Question: Consider circuit B. If we know that current is flowing, what is the
probability that switches 1 and 4 are functioning properly?

First I have calculated the probability of current flowing in B =0.9639 (it's correct).

The sample answer is below

> P （R1 ∩ R4|B）= P （R1 ∩ R4 ∩ B）/P（B).
> （R1 ∩ R4 ∩ B） = (R1 ∩ R4 )∩(R1 ∩ R3 )∪(R2 ∩ R4 ) = **( R1 ∩ R4 ∩ R3） ∪ （R2 ∩ R4 ）**.
> The probability of the above event is .9^3 + .9^2- .9^4 = 0.8829. So, the conditional probability in question is .8829/.9639 = 0.916.

I am not very sure how to derive the bold parts, and I think it should be **( R1 ∩ R4 ∩ R3） ∪ （R1∩R2 ∩ R4 ）** (distributive law)

*Can I get some help here? Appreciate it!*

Answer (score 1):

You calculated the probability of circuit working correctly

$P(B) = 0.81 + 0.81 - 0.81^2 = 0.9639 \ ,$ where $B$ is the event of circuit working correctly.

We are now trying to find $P(A | B)$ and for that we need to
find $P(A \cap B) \ \big(= P(B | A) \cdot P(A) \ \big)$ where $A = R_1 \cap R_4$.

$P(A) = 0.9^2$

If $R_1$ and $R_4$ function properly, the circuit will function properly so long as, at least one of $R_2$ and $R_3$ function properly.

$P(B|A) = P(R_2 \cup R_3) = 1 - P(R'_2 \cap R'_3) = 1 - (1-0.9)^2 = 0.99$

$P(A \cap B) = 0.9^2 \times 0.99 = 0.8019$

So $P(A | B) = \displaystyle \frac{0.8019}{0.9639}$